Orthogonal projection of a double-sided cone onto a plane
I would like to solve the following problem:

a double cone with vertex at the origin of coordinates (0, 0, 0) is given (See fig. 1). The blue cone is symmetrical to the yellow one w.r.t. the origin;
a plane through the origin is given with arbitrary orientation (it may intersect the cone at the only origin or also section the cone);
I would like to derive the orthogonal projection of the cone onto the plane. By "derive", I mean a description, either Cartesian or parametric or both, of the boundary of the projected cone.

For completeness, I include the mathematical definition of the yellow cone (See fig.2). Note that the scalar $\overline{f}_t$ and the set of unit vectors $\hat{\mathcal{U}}_t$ are known.  .
一
Thanks in advance!


What is a bicone?

I have changed the title, I hope it sounds more familiar...
